# Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'culture') on Umbraco 10.2.0 external Auth MS AAD Auto Linking

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, umbraco

I'm trying to implement Microsoft Active Directory External Auth for my Backoffice user in Umbraco version 10.2.0 following the documentations (https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Security/Authenticate-with-Active-Directory/ and https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Security/Auto-linking/) the implementation works when the user already exists and I did manual linking, however when when user doesn't exist the site becomes blank on redirect from authenticating and when I check console the following error occurred:

[07:29:43 ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'culture')
at Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services.LocalizedTextService.GetAllStoredValues(CultureInfo culture)
at Umbraco.Cms.Web.BackOffice.Controllers.BackOfficeController.LocalizedText(String culture)
at lambda_method57(Closure , Object )
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Middleware.BasicAuthenticationMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Umbraco.Cms.Web.BackOffice.Middleware.BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderErrorMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at SixLabors.ImageSharp.Web.Middleware.ImageSharpMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, Boolean retry)
at StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfilerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\projects\dotnet\src\MiniProfiler.AspNetCore\MiniProfilerMiddleware.cs:line 121
at Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Middleware.UmbracoRequestMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
at Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Middleware.UmbracoRequestMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Middleware.PreviewAuthenticationMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Middleware.UmbracoRequestLoggingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

My implementation is as follows:

- OpenIdConnectBackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions.cs

```
  public class OpenIdConnectBackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions>
    {
        public const string SchemeName = "OpenIdConnect";

        /// <summary>
        ///     Configures an instance of <see cref="OpenIdConnectBackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions"/> class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">
        ///     A <see cref="string"/> representing a name of the scheme
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="options">
        ///     A <see cref="BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions"/> representing the options to configure
        /// </param>
        public void Configure(string name, BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions options)
        {
            if (name != "Umbraco." + SchemeName)
            {
                return;
            }

            Configure(options);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Configures an instance of <see cref="OpenIdConnectBackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions"/> class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="options">
        ///     A <see cref="BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions"/> representing the options to configure
        /// </param>
        public void Configure(BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions options)
        {
            options.ButtonStyle = "btn-danger";
            options.Icon = "fa fa-windows";
            options.AutoLinkOptions = new ExternalSignInAutoLinkOptions(
                autoLinkExternalAccount: true,
                defaultUserGroups: new[] { Constants.Security.EditorGroupAlias },
                defaultCulture: "en-US",
                allowManualLinking: false
            )
            {
                OnAutoLinking = (autoLinkUser, loginInfo) =>
                {
                    autoLinkUser.IsApproved = true;
                },
                OnExternalLogin = (user, loginInfo) =>
                {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            options.DenyLocalLogin = false;
            options.AutoRedirectLoginToExternalProvider = false;
        }
```

- MicrosoftIdentityExtensions.cs

```
 public static class MicrosoftIdentityExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Adds Microsoft Authentication configuration <see cref="AddMicrosoftIdentity" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="builder">
        ///     Umbraco builder builds initializes services for umbraco
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="config">
        ///     Config has the options to configure Google Authentication
        /// </param>
        public static IUmbracoBuilder AddMicrosoftIdentity(this IUmbracoBuilder builder, IConfiguration config)
        {
            //TODO: to follow-up on the issue logged in Umbraco for Auto-Linking not working correctly: https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started//110241-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-culture-on-ms-aad-external-auth-auto-linking
            builder.Services.ConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectBackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions>();

            builder.AddBackOfficeExternalLogins(logins =>
            {
                const string schema = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                logins.AddBackOfficeLogin(backOfficeAuthenticationBuilder =>
                {
                    backOfficeAuthenticationBuilder.AddMicrosoftAccount(backOfficeAuthenticationBuilder.SchemeForBackOffice(schema),
                        options =>
                        {
                            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

                            options.AuthorizationEndpoint = config.GetValue<string>("AuthProviders:AzureAD:auth_url");
                            options.TokenEndpoint = config.GetValue<string>("AuthProviders:AzureAD:token_uri");
                            options.ClientId = config.GetValue<string>("AuthProviders:AzureAD:client_id");
                            options.ClientSecret = config.GetValue<string>("AuthProviders:AzureAD:client_secret");
                            options.CallbackPath = config.GetValue<string>("AuthProviders:AzureAD:callback_path");

                            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Role, "role");
                            options.SaveTokens = true;

                            options.Scope.Add("openid");
                            options.Scope.Add("email");
                            options.Scope.Add("profile");
                            options.UsePkce = true;

                        });
                });
            });
            return builder;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Can you share appsettings.json?

Comment: "AzureAD": {
      "auth_url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
      "token_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token",
      "client_id": "<client id>",
      "client_secret": "<client secret>",
      "redirect_uris": [
        "https://localhost:44328/umbraco-signin-microsoft"
      ],
      "javascript_origins": [
        "https://localhost:44328"
      ],
      "callback_path": "/umbraco-signin-microsoft"
    }

Answer (score 0):

I've hit the same error in Umbraco 10.3.2. I've also based my code around the [auto-linking](https://docs.umbraco.com/v/10.x-lts/umbraco-cms/reference/security/auto-linking) and [Azure AD auth](https://docs.umbraco.com/v/10.x-lts/umbraco-cms/reference/security/authenticate-with-active-directory) documentations from Umbraco just like you've had done.

There were two issues in my code implementation:

1. My `AzureAdUsersExternalLoginProviderOptions` class was checking for the wrong scheme name
2. My Azure AD Account is an `ExternalAzureAD` identity type, which causes an invalid username error in the auto-link.

### 1. Fixing the scheme issue

The example code shows a connection to an Open ID Connect Service.

```cs
public const string SchemeName = "OpenIdConnect";
public void Configure(string name, BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions options)
{
    if (name != "Umbraco." + SchemeName)
    {
        return;
    }

    Configure(options);
}
```

This is easily fixed by using the Microsoft [AuthenticationScheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.microsoftaccount.microsoftaccountdefaults.authenticationscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0) constant.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount;

public void Configure(string name, BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions options)
{
    if (name != "Umbraco." + MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.Configure(options);
}
```

This seems to have been the main issue for your problem, as I can see you've found the solution here:

- https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/110241-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-culture-on-ms-aad-external-auth-auto-linking

The above however did not fix the `Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'culture')` error for me.

### 2. Fixing the Invalid Username error

This is the second issue that caused the error for me.

The Microsoft Account I use to login to the Azure AD Tenant `foobar.onmicrosoft.com` is an External Azure AD identity type user from the `contoso.onmicrosoft.com` Azure AD Tenant.

- The User properties look like this:
  [image: User Details of external AD user in Azure AD Tenant]
- With a valid e-mail address inside the `otherMails` property:
  [image: otherMails property contents]

In my own code I used the following mapping for setting the BackOffice User's e-mail address:

```cs
options.ClaimActions.MapCustomJson(ClaimTypes.Email, user => user.GetString("mail");
```

- This will not work since the mail property is empty on the fetched Azure AD User.
- Using `userPrincipleName` as fallback will also not work since it contains illegal characters in `anh-duc_contoso.com#EXT#@foobar.onmicrosoft.com`.

The only property we can fetch a valid e-mail address from is the `otherMails` property. We can achieve the mapping with this:

```cs
options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=otherMails,displayName,givenName,surname,id";
options.ClaimActions.MapCustomJson(ClaimTypes.Email, x =>
{
    return x.GetProperty("otherMails").EnumerateArray().First().ToString();
});
```

---

**All credits for this solution to HalldorLyngmo** who excellently explains the issue and workaround/solution here:

- https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/issues/13100#issuecomment-1364152763